# MySQL general and slow query logs not working

Tags: mysql, mysql-slow-query-log

I am attempting to get table-based general and slow query-logging working on my local machine. It works alright to file, but I really prefer to go straight to a table so I can use numerous analysis queries I've written over the years.

Here's what I'm using for the slow query log

```
SET GLOBAL slow_query_log = 'ON';
SET GLOBAL long_query_time = 0;
SET GLOBAL min_examined_row_limit = 0;
SET GLOBAL log_queries_not_using_indexes = 'ON';
SET GLOBAL log_slow_admin_statements = 'ON';
```

I made a video showing my attempt. I am using mysql 5.6.20 installed via boxen. I previously was using mysql 5.5.20 which seemed to work alright. It's been a while since I've upgraded, so I can't be 100% that chance is what broke it, but it is likely.

I have attempted rebooting, and uninstalling/reinstalling.

http://screencast.com/t/mrpJMDzYjSp

Comment: Can't watch the video from my PC atm but common problems I think of: Path of log set (if not it's in your default folder)? User Permissions Correct? etc: maybe the docs help you: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-logs.html

Comment: @bish what path? I'm trying to log to a table, not file.

Answer (score 0):

By default the log_output goes to the FILE. you need to explicitly set log_output variable: 
log_output=TABLE